# Two Q. That were on my Procedural Programming exam no one answered correctly

Tags: c++, procedural-programming

By the way, this was a written exam. These questions gave 4 points each out of a possible 100.

Question 1:
Write a small program that by using a single while-loop and an if-statement will print out the following on the screen: [warning: multiple numbers out in a string, or hard-coding the values into variables will give zero points]

1  4  9  16  25
1  4  9  16
1  4  9
1  4
1

Question 2:
Below is the equation for the Harmonic Mean. Write a small program that can take values of an array and calculate the harmonic mean of these.

x = n * ( n Sigma i=1 (1/xi) )

Do you have any answers?

Comment: Do YOU have any answers as yet? Please show your attempt.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Whatever can be the problem with the second question anyway?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about answering exam questions

Comment: It's actually an exam we went to in January, we have the questions that were in it and are trying to figure them out.

Comment: FWIW, the obvious way to approach the first question is nested for loops `for (int line = 1; line <= 5; ++line) { for (int column = 1; column <= 6 - line; ++column) { if (column > 1) std::cout << ' '; std::cout << column * column; } std::cout << '\n'; }`

Answer (score 3):

Question 1:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 5;
    while(j > 0)
    {
        std::cout << i*i << " ";

        if(i == j)
        {
            i = 1;
            --j;
            std::cout << "\n";
        }else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 4 9 16 25 
1 4 9 16 
1 4 9 
1 4 
1
```

Good enough?

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecd0c7230003e258)

Comment: You can also avoid the `else` if you need to.

Comment: I was expecting a template metaprogramming version :-)

Comment: Btw this is pretty horrible code. Don't write like that if you can avoid it.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. For shitty assignment you can't expect good code

Comment: Pretty much, we've been sitting here for about 2 hours trying to figure the question out. We have attempted some similar versions. We're all beginners in programming, and havn't found ANY tutorials that show how you can use the While loop and the if statement together. Not even when looking for iteration tutorials. Anyways...
Thanks alot, we really appreciate your response.

Comment: @juanchopanza Hmm something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4230f38bcca97484)?

Answer (score 1):

Since recursion was not forbidden one could try this:

```
#include <iostream>

void printLn(int i) {
    int j = 0;
    while(++j <= i)
        std::cout << j*j<<" ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    if(i > 1)
        printLn(i - 1);
}

int main() {
    printLn(5); 
}
```

See it working at: http://ideone.com/mrKUx0

It uses recursion to print the individual lines and the while loop to print each number in the lines. The if is used to abort the recursion when finished.

The other code is very straight forward:

```
#include <iostream>

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

int main() {
    float array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        sum += 1 / array[i];
    std::cout << "Harmonic Mean: " << ARRAY_SIZE / sum;
}
```

Again see: http://ideone.com/GQJqQn

Note that the harmonic mean is defined as `n/Sum(...)` not `n * Sum(...)`